# Prometheus redis exporter

Tags: redis, prometheus, exporter

Hi Team I have used https://github.com/oliver006/redis_exporter
for scraping the metrics from AWS elastic cache cluster to external prometheus

- job_name: 'redis_exporter_targets'
  static_configs:

  - targets:

    - redis://ncc.cache.amazonaws.com:6379
      metrics_path: /scrape
      relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [**address**]
    target_label: __param_target
  - source_labels: [__param_target]
    target_label: instance
  - target_label: **address**
    replacement: testing:9121

I am getting below error:-
Get "http://testing:9121/scrape?target=ncc.cache.amazonaws.com%3A6379": context deadline exceeded.
Any idea about the error. I am able to telnet this endpoint from my prometheus server.